# Filter DataFrame using .loc and asin from an Alphanumeric List

Tags: python, pandas, list, alphanumeric, pandas-loc

I am trying to filter a dataframe using a list with alphanumerical values. Here is a sample dataframe below:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| D0102 | 52 |
| Patients | 150 |
| D5175 | 71 |
| DaysWorked | 12 |

I created a list named "codes" to:

```
codes = ['D0102', 'D5175']
```

The code I used is shown below and the dataframe didn't pull up anything:

```
new_df= df.loc[df['A'].isin(codes)]
```

## **The desired output dataframe that I want to display is this:**

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| D0102 | 52 |
| D5175 | 71 |

When I changed the list named "codes" to:

```
codes = ['Patients', 'DaysWorked']
```

I used the same line of code:

```
new_df= df.loc[df['A'].isin(codes)]
```

The new dataframe pulled the correct data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Patients | 150 |
| DaysWorked | 12 |

Comment: Will you please provide the result of `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`? When I run `df.loc[df['A'].isin(codes)]` I get the correct results.

Comment: You are using codes = ['D0102', 'D5175'] for the list? Because when I ran it, it gives me the same output.

Comment: Yes, I am. I copied all your code and ran it. I suspected - and Mayank also as you can see below - that there might be extra spaces/newlines/whatnot at the end or start of some of your strings...check out the answer below.

Comment: Yes that was the reason. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance that the column `A` of your `df` might have some *`unwanted whitespaces`* in it. You might wanna do this:

```
df.loc[df['A'].str.strip().isin(codes)]
```